# Stop Spyder opening last used scripts

Tags: spyder

If you close Spyder while scripts are open in the Editor pane, these same scripts will be loaded next time Spyder is started.  Is there any way to disable this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) No, there is no way to prevent Spyder from opening again the files you left open before closing it.

Comment: Oh well!  Thanks Carlos

Comment: If you are interested on having this in a future Spyder version, please open an issue in our [issues tracker](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder) and we'll take a look at it.